# Symfony 3 workflow definitions

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to setup Symfony 3 [workflow](http://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/state-machines.html) definitions config inside it related bundle and load into the framework?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try putting it into the config.yml file, in a different bundle in your code?

Comment: Yes, that's just a config.yml inside your bundle. You'll have a import it from your main app config.yml.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Yes I tried import from `config.yml` like this `{ resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/Vendor/Bundle/Resources/config/workflows.yml"  }` but it doesn't like it. Only this version work `{ resource: "../../src/Vendor/Bundle/Resources/config/workflows.yml" }`. Is  `%kernel.root_dir%` not allowed inside imports? And I am actually looking for a way without having add workflow definitions directly inside the main app config.yml instead they will load directly when bundle is register. Thanks

Comment: How do you get the workflow to be also in Console ? Can you please share ?
http://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/dumping-workflows.html $ php bin/console workflow:dump name > out.dot

Comment: @MartinFasani After you have your workflow listed om config. It should be loaded to symfony console. Can you try `php bin/console workflow:dump your-workflow-name` without pipe into *.dot. You should see `digraph workflow {......}` output in your console. If that fail try to pass `-vvv` flag to see more output.